# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un buscador con php que ejecute subconsultas?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, buscador

Este es el archivo donde se muestra la consulta múltiple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>Busqueda de Productos</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilosprod1.css">
        <form action=""></form> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include("conexion.php");

        echo "<div class='cont-busqueda'>";
        while ($imagen = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {


            echo "<input type='submit' value='$imagen[Producto]'>";

            echo "<div class='cont-img'>

                <img class='img-zoom'  src='$imagen[Ruta]'>

                  </div>";

        }
        echo "</div>";
        ?>
        <script src="scripts/zoom.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Código donde se hace la consulta:

```
<?php 
    include("conexion.php");

    $buscador = $_POST['buscarArt'];
    mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$buscador);

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM catalogo_cat WHERE Producto LIKE '%$buscador%' OR Precio LIKE '%$buscador%'";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
    $numero_busqueda = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);


    if ($numero_busqueda == false) {

            echo "<script>
                    alert('Término de búsqueda no encontrado');
                    window.location.href='index.html';
                    </script>";
    }else {
        if ($numero_busqueda  > 1) {
            include "plantilla_prods.php"; 
        }else{
            include "plantilla_prod.php";
        }

    } ?>
```

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo una tabla que contiene artículos y las imágenes de dicho artículo. Cuando se realiza la consulta, logré colocar en archivos distintos si la consulta es sólo de un artículo (individual) en específico o si es en general (varios) pero deseo regresar a la vista de individual de un artículo cuando se selecciona (usando un `input` o una etiqueta `a`) dicho artículo.

Muchas gracias y espero mi pregunta sea clara puesto que creo que esto se puede hacer con subconsultas.

Comment: Hola @MarcAnt. Bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta a agregando la parte relevante de tu código donde se genera la tabla de la consulta para varios? Sería mucho más sencillo ayudarte así

Comment: Listo amigo @Mariano

Comment: Haber no entendí, cual es tu error ó problema en el código?

Answer (score 1):

1-Esto no lo entiendo "logré colocar en archivos distintos si la consulta es sólo de un artículo (individual) en específico o si es en general (varios)", pero como lo lograste pues perfecto.

2-(supongo en la tabla),"deseo regresar a la vista de individual de un artículo cuando se selecciona (usando un input o una etiqueta a) dicho artículo".
Pues esto lo puedes lograr de tal forma que al pinchar en cada fila de la tabla, celda, producto o como lo tengas que te envíe a la vista individual de cada producto.

3-te pongo un ejemplo de una tabla mia para que al pulsar sobre cada tema (fila de la tabla), te muestre ese tema. Deberías de crear la tabla dinámicamente y en el location: cargar como ruta el resultado de las consultas (que entiendo devuelve una ruta de imagen del producto o del producto en si).

```
 <table id="tabla_contenidos">
  <!--Como argumento le paso la carpeta del lenguaje y el archivo concreto:-->
  <tr onclick="window.document.location='/paginaWeb/php/contenido.php?tema=lenguaje1/apuntes_batch1.pdf'">                   
    <td class="botones_ver">TEMA 1: Apuntes btch</td>                    
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="window.document.location='/paginaWeb/php/contenido.php?tema=lenguaje1/apuntes_batch2.pdf'">                   
    <td class="botones_ver">TEMA 2: Apuntes btch</td>                    
 </tr>
 <tr onclick="window.document.location='/paginaWeb/php/contenido.php?tema=lenguaje1/apuntes_batch3.pdf'">                   
    <td class="botones_ver">TEMA 3: Apuntes btch</td>                    
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Espero ayudarte, sino intenta darnos mas pistas de lo que quieres.